# phpMyAdmin - Error "Call to a member function getPath on null" on Docker container

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin

I have installed a fresh Docker Container from arm32v7/php:7.1-apache-stretch image.
After downloaded on phpMyAdmin and try to show the login page, I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPath() on null in
/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php:439 Stack trace: #0
/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php(298):
PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::initializeTheme() #1 /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/setu
/lib/common.inc.php(21): require_once('/var/www/html/p...') #2 /var/ww
/html/phpMyAdmin/setup/index.php(15): require('/var/www/html/p...') #3 {main} thrown 
in /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php on line 439
```

Do you have any idea to help me?

Thanks!